# Magento 2 : Custom Column Error

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, grid, resource-model

So, I have added a column to sales_order table. It is varchar type and it has some data in it.

I found tutorial:

[here](https://magenable.com.au/magento-ecommerce/modifying-default-magento-2-sales-order-grid-adding-coupon-code-column/)

that show what I want to achieve exactly.

Now, I am running Magento 2.2.3. and the exact same tutorial is not working for me. It just shows loading element and says

> Attention Something went wrong.

and then there is echoed error: "Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state.
"

So, here are my classes and xmls:

**Collection.php**

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection;

class Collection extends OriginalCollection
{
    protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {
        $joinTable = $this->getTable('sales_order');

        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ["so" => $joinTable],
            'main_table.entity_id = so.entity_id',
            array('customer_manager')
        );

        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }


}
```

di.xml

```
 <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sales_order_grid_data_source"
                  xsi:type="string">Silk\Customerstaff\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

sales_order_grid.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="customer_manager">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Manager</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="customer_manager" xsi:type="string">sales_order.customer_manager</item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Silk\Customerstaff\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Order\CustomerManagerOptions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

And CustomerManagerOptions.php

```
class CustomerManagerOptions
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $options;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
    {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Get options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function optionarray()
    {
        \Zend_Debug::dump('levu levic');
        if ($this->options === null) {
            $this->options = $this->collectionFactory->create()->toOptionArray();
        }

        return array(array('value' => 'Vukasin Vulovic', 'label' => 'Vukasin Vulovic'));
    }


}
```

Does anybody have any idea why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: You have a value in sales_order table right?? say it as coupon column

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran Yes, I have customer_manager column in sales_order table

Comment: So you want to fetch that into sales_order_grid and list it in grid view right?

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran yep, show it in grid and be able to filter it and sort it.

Comment: Do you have same column in sales_order_grid table as sales_order table

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran no, I don't

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Add a column in **sales_order_grid** table like you have in **sales_order**

Then add a **sales_order_grid.xml** in the below path

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

add the below code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                         
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="sales_order_columns">
<column name="customer_manager">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Column Name Goes here</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>                                                    
</columns>                                                   
</listing>
```

then add **di.xml** in the below path

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/di.xml

add the below code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                   
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
<arguments>
    <argument name="columns">
        <item name="customer_manager" xsi:type="string">sales_order.customer_manager</item>
    </argument>
</arguments>                                                     
</virtualType>                                                        
</config>
```

> NOTE : When you post data into sales_order table next time then it will also be added into sales_order_grid table as then xml will list the column in grid view and you can add filter and sortable option to it.

Run below commands after you made these changes

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes, it works, great! Now the thing is is that I want to filter it via select, how to achieve that?

Comment: If it helps you means, do accept it so others will get benefit and what do you mean by filter via select.Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I will when you answer my question to the end. So, I need to have a filter, not text type but select, where it would show me all the customer_manager in a dropdown.

Comment: after argument put this <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Namespace\Modulename\Model\Config\Source\File</item>

then make it as select then load the collection of array whatever you want to display it as option array.

Comment: This file Namespace\Modulename\Model\Config\Source\File.php should have the optionarray() to list it in the select dropdown and it may be static or dynamic up to your requirement. thanks

Comment: Thats not working

Comment: Update you code please

Comment: I edited the question, please find CustomerManagerOptions and updated sales_order_grid.xml, please let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Did you get the options in filter select or not? by above code

Comment: No, i didn't, it doesnt trigger my class

Answer (score 0):

Modify your **sales_order_grid.xml**, add the `options` and `component`in column:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="customer_manager">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Silk\Customerstaff\Model\Config\Source\CustomerManager</item>
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Manager</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="customer_manager" xsi:type="string">sales_order.customer_manager</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**EDIT**  Add this file to this Path

> Silk\Customerstaff\Model\Config\Source\CustomerManager;
>
> **CustomerManager.php**

```
<?php

namespace Silk\Customerstaff\Model\Config\Source;

class CustomerManager implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
/**
 * Options getter
 *
 * @return array
 *
 */
public function toOptionArray()
{
    return [
        ['value' => 0, 'label' => __('Option 1')],
        ['value' => 1, 'label' => __('Option 2')]
    ];
}
}
```

Comment: This is what I get if I use your code: Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in /home/magecomm/rtam/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Element/AbstractOptionsField.php on line 59

Comment: edit your CustomerManagerOptions return like this `return array('value' => 'Vukasin Vulovic', 'label' => 'Vukasin Vulovic');`

Comment: Same thing happens...

Comment: which collectionFactory you are using in your customerManager?

Comment: It doesn't matter, even when I remove the constructor, it still throws the same error

Comment: check the updated answer